# Changing UILabel's text causes scrollview to jump

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uilabel

I'm using a timer to update UILabel's text property. UILabel is in vertical UIScrollView.

```
static func play() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
    }

@objc private static func timerUpdate(_ timer: Timer) {
        let progress = AudioManager.currentTime
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("didUpdateProgress"), object: self, userInfo: ["progress":progress])
    }
```

When the next function is called, currentTimeLabel.text is updated with new string.

```
func didUpdateProgress(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let progress = notification.userInfo?["progress"] as? Float {
            slider.setValue(progress, animated: true)
            currentTimeLabel.text = String(format: "%01i:%02i", Int(progress/60), Int(progress) % 60)
        }
    }
```

But if the scrollview is not in its initial position, that is contentOffset is not zero, every time currentTimeLabel.text changes, scrollView jumps up. I thought, explicitly set height constraint for this particular label will fix this behavior, but it didn't:(

What can I do to update with a timer my UILabel's text inside UIScrollView, so that scrollview wouldn't jump?

Comment: First, are you sure it's caused by setting the label text, as opposed to animating the slider?

Comment: @DonMag commenting out the line with updating currentTimeLabel fixes jumping

Comment: hmmm... there *must* be something else going on in your code... what happens if you comment-out the slider.setValue line instead?

Comment: @DonMag slider just stops updating, but scrollview still jumps in its initial position if I don't comment out updating currentTimeLabel =[

Comment: Are you using a sub-classed label that does some other stuff when the text is set? Or what else is going on? Clearly, setting the text of a UILabel inside a UIScrollView causing the scroll view to jump is *not* by design...

Comment: I'm not subclassing UILabel... I think it might be somehow connected with AutoLayout, since I'm changing text of the label, so its content size changes and scrollview probably recalculates something... I'll provide details if I solve it, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that I had described was in my `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method. Every time the view appears on the screen, I wanted the scrollview to reset its position. So I did it like this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
}
```

I had no idea that this method is called every time I change text property of the label. Well, now it seems absolutely clear, because changing the text makes the label to recalculate its width, but it wasn't so obvious in the beginning:)

Sorry, that I missed this part in the question. Trying to avoid unnecessary details and make the question minimal it's easy to omit something important, especially if you don't really know where the problem is located.

Comment: Had this exact same situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I follow this practise when i work on scrollView.
If you want to work with ScrollView you can follow this.

1. Take scrollView and do auto-layout top, left, bottom, right 0 constraint   to superview(Main View)
2. Take another View which will be your container view and do auto-layout as above (0 constraint)
3. Put your desired outlet and make sure you have pulled all the constraint most important top and bottom constraint to every outlet.if it needs height then give specific height.

[image]

4. This point should be one.:) make your view height bigger so that you can put your desired outlets and everything will be clear to you.

[image]

So when i write code just like this i found nothing unusual.That is jumping.Should try this one more time.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
var timer:Timer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.onTimerUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func  onTimerUpdate() {
    self.label1.text = "I have changed"
}
```

}

I pulled my scrollView to the bottom and after 4 seconds label text has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text might change the intrinsic content size of the UILabel. If the UILabel property `numberOfLines` is defined as 0 (default) it is allowed to grow depending on content. In this case the UILabel height might shrink/grow when setting the text. If you additionally specified autolayout constraints based on the intrinsic content size it might affect the scrollview behaviour. I'm not really sure about it.

So check it out or please provide additional informations:

- UIScrollView & UILabel auto layout constraints
- UILabel properties (numberOfLines=0?)